# Sphinx mock issue with django `get_user_model` in a custom pakage for django

Tags: django, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am creating a custom package for a django project. The package contains two authentication backends. I have modules configured as below,

```py
# Backend 1 module
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

UserModel = get_user_model()
# ModelBackend = object  # This will fix actual import issue and uses mocked import only

class AuthBackendOne(ModelBackend):
    pass
```

```py
# Backend 2 module
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

UserModel = get_user_model()  # here calls actual django method

class AuthBackendTwo(ModelBackend):
    pass
```

In my sphinx `conf.py` I have`autodoc_mock_imports = [ "django.conf", "django.contrib.auth" ]`

##### Issue:

The problem is when I generate sphinx-build for docs, in module 2 it is trying to call actual django `get_user_model()`. It is not considering that was mocked. By trying myself, I found the issue was when I use ModelBackend to base my custom backend class. No issue in importing ModelBackend, but using that breaks the module 2. Just before using `ModelBackend`, I have re-assigned to `object` and run sphinx-build with successful.

##### Findings:

For my test trials I have printed the UserModel and its type in the above two methods, (I didn't call the `get_user_model` function in this test)

cognito - CustomBackend 1
ldap - CustomBackend 2

- In the normal way (`ModelBackend` not reassigned to `object`):

  ```bash
  cognito sources... [ 33%] kala_common.auth.cognito                                                                                                                                                                         
  django.contrib.auth.get_user_model
  <class 'django.contrib.auth.get_user_model'>
  ldaping sources... [ 40%] kala_common.auth.ldap                                                                                                                                                                            
  <function get_user_model at 0x7f386829f1c0>
  <class 'function'>
  ```
- In the test method (`ModelBackend` reassigned as `object`):

  ```bash
  cognito sources... [ 33%] kala_common.auth.cognito                                                                                                                                                                         
  django.contrib.auth.get_user_model
  <class 'django.contrib.auth.get_user_model'>
  ldaping sources... [ 40%] kala_common.auth.ldap                                                                                                                                                                            
  django.contrib.auth.get_user_model
  <class 'django.contrib.auth.get_user_model'>
  ```

Note type of ldap in both : as function and as class

So, what should I do to fix the issue, I have tried including ModelBackend in autodoc mock as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve some django imports during sphinx-doc build for my package, I have made the below changes.

1. mocked `django.contrib.auth.__init__` (`get_user_model` is defined in there)
2. Also to work other django functionality I have setup a minimal django settings.

```py
# doc/source/conf.py  - configuration sphinx documentation

# ... other sphinx doc configuration

# this resolves importing issue of settings from django.conf
autodoc_mock_imports = [
    "django.conf",
    # ... rest of other mock modules
]

# this resolved get_user_model issue
sys.modules["django.contrib.auth.__init__"] = MagicMock()


# django minimal settings config
import django
from django.conf import settings

DJANGO_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
]
settings.configure(DEBUG=True, INSTALLED_APPS=DJANGO_APPS)
django.setup()
```

my previous answer did worked at that time, idk how!! But not working now, however this, completely fixes issues with sphinx-doc build now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using `MagicMock` on django's backend module I was able to solve the issue;

```py
# conf.py - of sphinx

from unittest.mock import MagicMock

sys.modules["django.contrib.auth.backends"] = MagicMock()
```

If anyone have any better solution, please do suggest me.